# What's the Pythonic way to loop through an iterator when the first few values are special?

Tags: python

The standard away is:

```
it = iter(sequence)
for value in it:
    print value
```

I'm using a third party library that returns an iterator with the first value being a header, the second value being metadata and the rest of the values being records.  I have tried something like:

```
db = dbfreader(f)
headers = db.next()
spec =  db.next()
record = db.next()
while record:
    print record
    record = db.next()
```

But that results in a StopIteration error

Comment: Your code is fine, `while record: print record` makes no sense. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes I did I missed the last line

Comment: Why are you reading the first record separately?  That value is not special.  Just read the headers and spec and then do `for record in db`.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- In OP's code, it is needed so that `while record` doesn't raise a `NameError`.

Comment: @mgilson: Well, yes, but why do it that way at all?

Comment: @BrenBarn -- I'm not saying that is the right way to do it, I'm just trying to explain why OP might have done it in the first place.  If he didn't realize he could iterate over the object directly and thought he needed to walk through it using `next`, that's the only way to do it. (And, as a side note, there's no guarantee that the object returned by `dbfreader` implements `def __iter__(self): return self` -- Of course that's the expected thing, but we don't know for sure ... I've definitely seen worse :-P )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first record is not special, it's just the first of all records, so there's no reason to read it ahead of time.

```
db = dbfreader(f)
headers = db.next()
spec =  db.next()
for record in db:
    print record
```

Comment: The important thing to know to understand this code is that all Python iterators are also *iterable*. That is, you can call `iter` on an iterator, and it will return the iterator unchanged. This happens implicitly in the `for` loop in this answer.

Comment: 2 comments, 1) use `next(db)` rather than `db.next()`.  2) this is definitely the cleanest way to do this and any *sane* object should work with this, but it is possible to design an object for which this idiom will fail.

Answer (score 1):

> The standard way is:

```
it = iter(sequence)
for value in it:
    print value
```

No need for the call to `iter` here, it gets done implicitly in the loop:

```
for value in sequence:
    print value
```

Ultimately, `iter(obj)` returns `obj.__iter__()`.  This gets called implicitly when you start a for loop:

```
for elem in x:
```

implicitly does

```
for elem in iter(x):
```

Then, in the loop, python calls `next` on the iterable returned by `iter(obj)` to get the various `elem`s until `next` raises a `Stopiteration`.

**So your loop could be written as:**

```
while True:
    print record
    try:
        record = next(db)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Or more succinctly and idiomatically (as long as `iter(db)` returns `db` which is pretty typical):

```
for record in db:
    print record
```

---

Generally, you can get the next value from an iterable using the `next` function -- but the object needs to have a `next` method (or `__next__` on python3.x).  If it's a sequence, you might need to call `iter` on the object first in this case:

```
>>> obj = ['header','header2','record1']
>>> next(obj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list object is not an iterator
>>> iobj = iter(obj)
>>> next(iobj)
'header'
>>> next(iobj)
'header2'
>>> for x in iobj:
...    print x
... 
record1
```

---

Note that you *can* suppress a `StopIteration` from being raised by `next` by supplying a second argument to be returned instead of raising `StopIteration`:

```
>>> next(iter([]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> next(iter([]),"Hello!")
'Hello!'
```

Seeing this, we find that you could also write your loop:

```
while record:
    print record
    record = next(db,False)
```

But the `for` loop is definitely the cleanest way to do it for most objects.